# False Discovery Rate (FDR) in fuzzySim package in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm fairly new to R and am trying to calculate the false discovery rate for a series of t tests I ran where I want q = 0.05.  It seems like the [FDR function in the fuzzySim package](https://rdrr.io/rforge/fuzzySim/man/FDR.html) is a nice solution, however I'm getting some error messages when I run the very examples in the fuzzySim description.  For example I do...

```
library(fuzzySim)

df <- data.frame(var = letters[1:5], pval = c(0.02, 0.004, 0.07, 0.03, 0.05))

p_value_info <- FDR(pvalues = df, correction = "fdr", q = 0.05, 
verbose = FALSE, simplif = TRUE)
```

And unfortunately, this is the error message I get...

```
Error in if (na.loss > 0) message(na.loss, " cases excluded due to missing or non-finite values.") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't know the package you're using but I'm guessing it just wants the vector of p-values so df$pval should be passed instead of df

Comment: No luck there when I tried ```p_value_info <- FDR(pvalues = df$pval, correction = "fdr", q = 0.05, verbose = FALSE, simplif = TRUE)``` And it specifically says in the description of the 'pvalues' argument that it looking for a data frame with 2 columns...thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently at the time of using this fuzzySim package, there was a bug in the code which is now fixed in the most updated development version (3.5) which can be installed with

```
install.packages("fuzzySim", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

I have confirmed that it now works with a data frame of variable names and p values.

A huge thanks to the author of this package, A. Márcia Barbosa, for updating the code.  Márcia informed me that an updated package will be uploaded to CRAN later this year.